# Could my servers configuration stop json from working?

Tags: php, mysql, json, highcharts

I am trying to work through a tutorial regarding getting a JSON string from MySQL and preparing it for highcharts, but it's not working and I have no idea why....

**HTML:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var chart;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.getJSON("data.php", function (json) {

                chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                    chart: {
                        renderTo: 'container',
                        type: 'line',
                        marginRight: 130,
                        marginBottom: 25
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Revenue vs. Overhead',
                        x: -20 //center
                    },
                    subtitle: {
                        text: '',
                        x: -20
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: 'Amount'
                        },
                        plotLines: [
                            {
                                value: 0,
                                width: 1,
                                color: '#808080'
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        formatter: function () {
                            return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                                this.x + ': ' + this.y;
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
                        layout: 'vertical',
                        align: 'right',
                        verticalAlign: 'top',
                        x: -10,
                        y: 100,
                        borderWidth: 0
                    },
                    series: json
                });
            });

        });

    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script src="js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="js/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

The JSON string is produced using the file

**data.php:**

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("*****", "*****", "*****");

if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("*****", $con);

$sth = mysql_query("SELECT revenue FROM projections_sample");
$rows = array();
$rows['name'] = 'Revenue';
while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($sth)) {
    $rows['data'][] = $r['revenue'];
}

$sth = mysql_query("SELECT overhead FROM projections_sample");
$rows1 = array();
$rows1['name'] = 'Overhead';
while ($rr = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $rows1['data'][] = $rr['overhead'];
}

$result = array();
array_push($result, $rows);
array_push($result, $rows1);

print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

If I enter a JSON string manually into **data.php** the charts is displayed as expected.

```
[{
"name": "Revenue",
"data": [23987, 24784, 25899, 25569, 25897, 25668, 24114, 23899, 24987, 25111, 25899, 23221]
}, {
"name": "Overhead",
"data": [21990, 22365, 21987, 22369, 22558, 22987, 23521, 23003, 22756, 23112, 22987, 22897]
}]
```

I'm assuming my connection details are correct, because if I purposely enter the wrong password I get the MySQL connection error...

```
“Could not connect: Access denied for user ‘*****’@'localhost’ (using password: YES)”
```

Also, I get `“True”` returned when I add `“echo @mysql_ping() ? ‘true’ : ‘false’;”` to the bottom of the page.

Because I'm convinced it should be working I'm wondering if there is anything related to server configuration that could be preventing me from using JSON?

Comment: *Obligatory:* The `mysql_*` functions will be [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: please, please, check for mysql errors after you execute a query: `$result = mysql_query("SELECT overhead FROM projections_sample"); if(!result) print mysql_error;` Its the first step at debugging..

Comment: What is actually being printed when you print the json encoded data? Try adding `alert(json)` to the javascript and see if it returns valid json!

Comment: data.php just gives me a blank white page atm...

@JasonMcCreary I didn't see much point in bringing the code in line with current standards if I couldn't get it to work in the first place. I have been trying to get a json output for over a week now from various tutorials...


@immulatin I get a blank page when I add `$result = mysql_query("SELECT overhead FROM projections_sample"); if(!result) print mysql_error;` the same as when its not added.


@MichaelWheeler Where about should I place `alert(json)`. sry I'm a total noob with java.

Comment: i gave you bad code. It should be `print mysql_error();` But @MichaelWheeler suggestion was good to debug what the javascript is receiving. You will want to put it after the getJSON method: `$.getJSON("data.php", function (json) { alert(json) ..`

Comment: @immulatin when I use `$.getJSON("data.php", function (json) { alert(json)` I get a pop up saying `Null`.

Comment: @immulatin If I manually enter the json string to data.php and then use `$.getJSON("data.php", function (json) { alert(json)` I get a popup saying `[object Object], [object Object]`

Comment: Add `var_dump($result);` `var_dump($rows);` `var_dump($rows1);` before `json_encode` and call `data.php` directly (`yourdomain.com/path/data.php`) to see results.

Comment: @furas I added the code you suggested and I actually see a response from data.php now...  `array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["name"]=> string(7) "Revenue" ["data"]=> array(12) { [0]=> string(5) "23280" [1]=> string(5) "24784" [2]=> string(5) "25899" [3]=> string(5) "25569" [4]=> string(5) "25897" } }` It goes on further but I run out of space to reply with if I show it you all :)

Comment: Your strings like string(5) "24784" needs to be numbers.

Comment: So `$result` is ok. Time for next test. What PHP version you have ? You can use `phpinfo();` - [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) require `PHP 5 >= 5.2.0`.

Comment: By the way: maybe your server doesn't show error messages. Create incorrect line (for example remove some `;`) and run script again. Is there any error message ?

Comment: @Sebastian Bochan he use `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` to change string to integer.

Comment: Yes, but output I see strings, so it is something wrong with encoding.

Comment: Output is from `var_dump($result)`. `Json_encode` generate empty page.

Comment: @SG129 - I found that `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` require PHP 5.3.3 ([json.constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php))

Comment: BTW: You could use [json_last_error](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) to test if there was problem with `json_encode`.

Comment: I'm using PHP Version 5.2.17. When I remove a `;` I get a HTPP 500 error. 
I wasn't aware that JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK wasn't supported on my version, that must be the issue. :( Is there another way for me to achieve this using php v5.2.17?

Comment: @furas Also, if it's relevant My JSON version is 1.2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you can't use `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` (because it requires PHP 5.3.3 ([json.constants](http://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php)))

you can [cast](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting) to `int`  [`$number = (int)"1234";`]

in

```
while ($r = mysql_fetch_array($sth)) {
    $rows['data'][] = (int)$r['revenue']; // <- (int)
}
```

and

```
while ($rr = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $rows1['data'][] = (int)$rr['overhead']; // <- (int)
}
```

than

```
print json_encode($result);
```

Comment: That is just awesome, Iv'e spent so many hours trying to solve this one. learnt a fair few things from the exercise too. Can't thank you enough... :)